# Selenium fetch text not by xml

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, angular-ngmodel

I am looking to find another way to fetch text from aplication, where this text is hidden in xml. I mean there is no raw test or attribute containing string i want to fetch (below placeholder i want to feth text from):

```
<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required cs-has-visited ng-touched" placeholder="Mobile" ng-model="player.address.mobile" required="" style="">
```

I ofc can see this as user. I can enter new text (field is editable) or clean it.

Answer (score 1):

If you would use [`Protractor`](http://angular.github.io/protractor), you can locate the element by model and [evaluate](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate) the model value:

```
var elm = element(by.model("player.address.mobile"));
elm.evaluate("player.address.mobile").then(function (modelValue) {
    console.log(modelValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it already! You need to take attribute 'value' even if it's not visible, as it has to be there.

Comment: If you found your answer, please make sure you come back and accept the answer so this question gets marked as answered. Thanks!